# Which free editing program has an preset 'Relief' adjustment?

Tags: software, post-processing, photo-editing

Before my XP went walk-about (and the hard drive went with it) I was using a free editing program that allowed a "one-touch" (well, actually it was three clicks — but who's counting...) adjustment to the *"relief"* of a photo — which created a slightly more three dimensional look or depth-with-clarity — but I cannot recall the name of it. 
Anyone know?

Comment: This is going to be hard unless someone knows the specific program, because normally "relief" in post-processing software refers to a cheesy faux _bas relief_ effect where the filter does an edge detect and uses grayscale with light and dark to give a (usually really bad) pseudo-3D look.

Comment: Can you include a sample image of this effect?

Comment: do you mean "bas-relief"?

Answer (score 1):

What you refering as relief is as mattdm said a highlight shadow filter more like to give any object a stone-a-like surface look. What you are trying to ask is "Clarity" and/or "Structure". You can use [snapseed](http://www.snapseed.com/) which is free now after google bought it and there are many filters you can enjoy and very easy to use.